# Hosting markdown with Markserve requiring authentication

Tags: nginx, markdown, hosting

I have a lot of markdown I would like to host with markserve but would also like to only provide access to the hosted markdown to authenticated users. What is the best way of accomplishing this? I was thinking nginx as a reverse proxy setup would facilitate this. Any suggestions, links to configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I settled on allmark markdown server, works quite well and fast with in-built authentication.